Does SQL Server ALWAYS enforce referential integrity with foreign key constraints?
In other words, is it possible to create a situation where there are orphaned child records, for which no parent exists anymore?
Imagine a situation where ON DELETE CASCADE cannot be used and an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger is used on the parent table instead. If I define my IOD trigger poorly, not properly cleaning up all the child records before deleting the parent, would SQL server allow this to happen? Or would it realise that the deletion of the parent will leave an orphaned child and throw an exception anyway?
I use MS SQL Server 2016 and I am wondering if I can always blindly rely on a left join on a foreign key (properly defined as a foreign key constraint) not creating any null records in the right hand side table.

When you tried this out, and tested what occurs when you try to delete rows that have "children" what did you find occurred? Why was it not what you expected?

I didn't try it. Its a theoretical question.

Well then go and try...

I don't understand the last sentence.

if you have an FK, then yes, it will be honored whichever way you delete the records later. But not sure what you mean with LEFT JOIN, why not use INNER JOIN. But also, if you have a Header + Rows tables, then LEFT JOINing rows from header might still generate NULLs, because FK is usually from Rows => Header. Oh yeah, one could disable FKs so technically it's possible that records are dirty. I think your question is actually something else, so might as well ask the real question instead of going around

Without disabling or dropping FKs, no this is not possible. FKs are enforced using SERIALIZABLE locking always, so if you find an orphaned FK that would be a bug, and would show up in a DBCC CHECKDB run as an error. Rather than creating an INSTEAD OF trigger, why not just delete them from the application directly?

Ok after thinking about it a bit more I can answer my own question. The child table controls whether a parent record can be deleted, via the ON DELETE XY setting of the foreign key. So if I don't set ON DELETE CASCADE on the child table, and the IOD trigger on the parent table does not delete the child record before attempting to delete the parent record, the deletion of the parent record will be blocked. That is because the implicit default setting is ON THE DELETE NO ACTION
What I meant with the join example was: "Can I be sure that a corresponding parent record always exists for every child record in a foreign key relationship"
